# JQUERY/JavaScript - trouble code causing google chrome to freeze

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have some code that loops and calls a function that does some calculations on a table. I have painfully gone through a very large amount of code to pinpoint this particular code as the cause for chrome to freeze for about a minute. Does anyone have any suggestions on how this code maybe improved from a performance perspective?

```
function getAverage(a, b) {
    var sum = 0;
    var count = 0;
    $(a).each(function () {
        $content = $(this).html();       
        var tdTxt = parseFloat($(this).text(), 10) || 0;
        if ($(this).hasClass(b)) {
            var theAvg = parseFloat((sum / count), 10) || 0;
            $(this).text(theAvg.toFixed(2));
            sum = 0;
            count = 0;
        } else {
            sum += parseFloat(tdTxt);
            if ($content == '') {
            }
            else {
                count += 1;
            }
        }
    })
}
        var el1 = $('#rackPlan1 > thead > tr > th:gt(17):not(.totalRow)');    
        var starter = 19; 
        for (i = 0; i < el1.length; i++) {
            $('#rackPlan1 > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(' + starter + ')').each(function () {
                getAverage('#rackPlan1 > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(' + starter + ')', 'subTotal');
            })
            starter += 1;
        }
```

Many Thanks

Comment: You might have better luck asking this question on [Code Reivew](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: A loop in a loop that calls a function with a loop is quite heavy

Comment: Use setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame to slow down the execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly looking at the`getAverage()` function, I would suggest:

## 1

```
function getAverage(a, b) {

    var $this, $content, tdTxt, theAvg; // it's marginally less expensive to declare vars at a higher scope and re-use them in a lower scope
    
    var sum = 0;
    var count = 0;
    
    $this = $(a); // cache this nth-child received from the $.each loop
    $content = $this.html();
    tdTxt = parseFloat($this.text(), 10) || 0;
    if ($this.hasClass(b)) {
        theAvg = parseFloat((sum / count), 10) || 0;
        $this.text(theAvg.toFixed(2));
        sum = 0;
        count = 0;
    } else {
        sum += parseFloat(tdTxt);
        if ($content == '') {
        }
        else {
            ++count; // this micro-optimization makes it marginally faster
        }
    }
}
```

---

## 2

Looking at the other block of code:

```
var el1 = $('#rackPlan1 > thead > tr > th:gt(17):not(.totalRow)');
var starter = 19;

$('#rackPlan1 > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(' + starter + ')').nextUntil(':nth-child(' + ((starter+el1.length)-1) + ')').each(function(){
    getAverage(this, 'subTotal');
});
```

---

## 3

I am not thoroughly experienced in `:nth-child` so maybe this is better?

```
$('#rackPlan1 > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(' + starter + 'n+' + ((starter+el1.length)-1) + ')').each(function(){
    getAverage(this, 'subTotal');
});
```

---

## 4

If the `nth-child` stuff fails then simply try replacing:

```
getAverage('#rackPlan1 > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(' + starter + ')', 'subTotal');
```

with

```
getAverage(this, 'subTotal');
```

Comment: thank you for the great suggestions, I have implemented them...unfortunately my issue remains

Comment: It looks like you have some pretty serious inefficiencies in your `nth-child` calls so I am working on updating my answer.

Comment: @sm1l3y Please see the edit. I believe I got the arithmetic correct for `.nextUntil(':nth-child(' + ((starter+el1.length)-1) + ')')` but I am not positive if it is the correct stop-point.

Comment: just tried it out, this feels very close...the performance issue is completely gone however the values returned to the cells are 0

Comment: ok so what is happening now it is only returning to the first or last cell

Comment: @sm1l3y I think I see the issue and updated the `getAverage()` function. I've numbered my solution pieces so try mixing 1+2 or 1+3

Comment: your efforts and time are much appreciated sir, unfortunately still not working for me...for example the averages are returning zero when some of the cells above are 1...it does not appear to be the average function where the issue remains but the calling it

Comment: @sm1l3y I am honestly not sure how else to help you because I am not familiar with your table structure. Would you be able to provide a screenshot or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) an example of what your table looks like and what you are trying to accomplish in which cells? I won't be back online for a few hours so if you can provide an example in the meantime then it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @sm1l3y any luck?

Comment: here is a jsfiddle example:https://jsfiddle.net/khemikal/2azzqeh9/ the bottoms total is where the get average function returns to, calcs on the cells above...let me know if you need any more info

Comment: @sm1l3y Very nice but unfortunately jsfiddle went down while I was messing with the code so I won't be able to check it out better until the site comes back up lol

Comment: Here is my latest jsfiddle...converted a .each into native js for performance...so close I believe...for some reason the average function (which returns to the bottom row) that applies to proto A-M returns 0 instead of 1 >> https://jsfiddle.net/khemikal/2azzqeh9/2/

Comment: @sm1l3y What happened to "Bottoms Total"? Anyways I think I see what you are trying to do now...

Comment: i must have all those checks in place per the getaverage function...because I could have multiple rows with different categories

Comment: @sm1l3y It would be nice if you could use my fiddle and update the `<table>` structure to reflect your actual situation because your fiddle only had one category and I think it's pretty obvious that I am not psychic.

Comment: appreciate your help, you have given me enough where i think i cain solve this...accepting answer

Comment: @sm1l3y Nice, good luck! If you get stuck with my Fiddle, just let me know.